# Seam page actions and conversation

Tags: jsf, seam, seam-gen

I have created my application using seam-gen. Seam-gen has created all the crud operations & forms for all my objects. They all inherit from seam's EntityHome.

I have this requirement that I need to create from an object A another object B (A has a List). So I need to redirect the user to the B form, save a new B object, and then redirect him to the original A form with the updated List contents.

I am a newbie in Seam and I am not sure how to implement this properly.

Edit: I am using seam version 2.2.2 final.

Comment: Try avoid using the entityHome, will give you headace in the long run. Do your own action classes for each page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action class (similar to how entityHome works without the baggage that comes with it) to manage your contained entities and their behaviors.  If no relationship exists between the entities you can make one here.
Refreshing the original list can be tricky, but once you have some code started post it.
So I would start with something like:

```
 Class ActionBean {
     ClassAObj classA;
     List<ClassBObj> classBList;

     public void methodThatLinksAandB() {
          // ... stuff happens here
     }

     // getters and setter for view
     // private worker methods

 }
```